# Connecting to an instrument with Python (Pyvisa)

Tags: python-3.x, gpib, pyvisa

I am trying to automate a Keithley 2000 source meter with python. I used the following code to connect to the instrument (GPIB):

```
import pyvisa
rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
rm.list_resources()
('ASRLCOM1::INSTR', 'ASRLCOM3::INSTR')
```

Since gpib is not founded here, I tried all the following and I got the following errors:

```
from gpib_ctypes import gpib
AttributeError: function 'ibsre' not found

my_instrument = rm.open_resource('GPIB::20::INSTR')
AttributeError: No class registered for InterfaceType.gpib, INSTR

import visa
DMM = visa.ResourceManager().get_instrument('GPIB::20::INSTR')
DMM.ask('*IDN?')
ValueError: No class registered for InterfaceType.gpib, INSTR
```

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using a windows PC. Have you got a VISA library installed?

We first want to establish that the GPIB can be seen. You can either use "NI Max" or "Keysight connection expert" to check the connection to the instrument. These will also install the VISA library. Google either SW and there will be instructions of how to install and connect to your instrument.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had the NI Visa driver, and other drivers from NI installed on my PC.  I installed the IO libraries suite and the problem solved.